# Add confidence intervals with specific values to a graph line with two series

Tags: r, ggplot2, confidence-interval

I want to reproduce the following graph:

[image]

And my data is the following, where the blue line is `complete_preds_means` and the orange line is `contrafact`:

```
structure(list(dias = structure(c(19052, 19053, 19054, 19055, 
19056, 19057, 19058, 19059, 19060, 19061, 19062, 19063, 19064, 
19065, 19066, 19067, 19068, 19069, 19070, 19071), class = "Date"), 
    complete_preds_means = c(341.07434, 381.59167, 455.47815, 
    485.05597, 527.60876, 562.63965, 602.48975, 624.663, 626.5637, 
    527.2239, 420.71643, 389.30804, 378.74396, 366.61548, 361.36566, 
    363.37253, 319.31824, 314.39688, 303.60342, 294.8934), contrafact = c(364.5, 
    358.89, 466.64, 470.11, 464.25, 487.27, 591.2, 715.33, 628.02, 
    505.98, 402.9, 316.81, 323.35, 358.61, 354.26, 369.5, 317.01, 
    336.5, 285.33, 270.91), complete_preds_lower = c(320.6368042, 
    361.7870895, 432.4487762, 461.2275833, 503.2255051, 535.7108551, 
    576.3850006, 597.9762146, 601.4407013, 504.0448837, 398.7777023, 
    368.0046799, 356.3603165, 345.5847885, 339.9679932, 342.7514801, 
    298.3247482, 293.4419693, 282.5286865, 275.4635284), complete_preds_upper = c(359.9897186, 
    402.5708664, 477.4746765, 508.7775711, 550.3326447, 587.6521027, 
    628.5320251, 649.9691833, 649.4831665, 547.9886108, 442.046402, 
    410.8121475, 399.0208908, 389.8615128, 387.4929993, 386.2935928, 
    340.140834, 336.3622116, 324.793483, 315.4606934)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

So far I have tried this:

```
plot_fig4 <- ggplot()+
  geom_line(data=fig4, aes(x=dias, y=complete_preds_means), colour="blue")+
  geom_line(data=fig4, aes(x=dias, y=contrafact), colour="red") + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=fig4$complete_preds_lower, ymax=fig4$complete_preds_upper))+
  labs(y="Clase ($)",
       x="") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(from=100, to=800, by=100))+
  scale_x_date(expand = c(0, 0), date_breaks="1 month", date_labels = "%b\n%Y")
```

But I only get this error: `Error: geom_ribbon requires the following missing aesthetics: x or y, xmin and xmax`

Comment: You need to add `x=dias` inside the `aes` of `geom_ribbon`. Better still, change your first line to `ggplot(fig4, aes(x=dias))` so that you don't need to do `data=fig4` and `x=dias` in every `geom` call

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told `geom_ribbon` what variable should be on the x axis. You *could* just add `x=fig4$dias` inside the `aes` of `geom_ribbon`, but this isn't the best way to use ggplot. Better to use ggplot's inheritance of data and aesthetic mappings to avoid repeating yourself and making mistakes along the way. If you change your first line to `ggplot(fig4, aes(x = dias))` you don't need to do `data=fig4` and `x=dias` in every geom call.

A couple of other issues are that you should map the color aesthetic to produce a legend, and make the `alpha` low on your ribbon so that it is semi-transparent. The ordering of layers is also important.

Finally, I have added some theme tweaks to make the plot more like the desired output.

```r
ggplot(fig4, aes(x = dias)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = contrafact, color = "Contrafact"), linewidth = 1) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = complete_preds_lower, ymax = complete_preds_upper),
                  fill = "deepskyblue4", alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line(aes(y = complete_preds_means, color = "Predicted"), linewidth = 1) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = as.Date("2022-03-13"),
             linetype = 4, colour = "green4") +
  labs(y = "Clase ($)", x = NULL) +
  scale_color_manual(NULL, values = c("orange", "deepskyblue4")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1:8 * 100) +
  scale_x_date(expand = c(0, 0), date_breaks = "1 month", 
               date_labels = "%b\n%Y") +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to add the green line on `2022-06-13`, like this: ``` geom_vline(aes(xintercept=as.integer(as.POSIXct("2022-06-13"))), linetype=4, colour="green")``` But I'm not getting anything.

Comment: @Maria it has to be `as.Date`, not `as.POSIXct`, and you don't need `as.integer`. See my update. I have had to change the date to 13th March for demonstration purposes, since your sample data didn't go as far as June. The principle is the same though.